# GMB - Removal of LocationState object in Business Information API

Tags: deprecated, google-my-business-api

Google deprecated the old **GMB API v4.9 account.locations.get endpoint**, and replaced it with **Business Information API v1 locations.get**.

Code change that affects me is:

- [Removal of LocationState object. The existing fields have been moved into Metadata](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/businessinformation/change-log).

The new Metadata object does not return the attributes LocationState object contained before. The ones I'm interested in are:

- isVerified
- isPublished
- isSuspended
- isDisabled
- isDisconnected
- etc...

**My question is:**
How could I get this data without using deprecated endpoints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Verification API [getVoiceOfMerchantState](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/verifications/rest/v1/locations/getVoiceOfMerchantState)

```
isVerified  (verify),
isPublished (hasVoiceOfMerchant=true AND hasBusinessAuthority=true),
isSuspended (complyWithGuidelines),
isDuplicate (resolveOwnershipConflict).
isDisabled & isDisconnected have no equivalent in new API
```

Comment: Thanks Elisa, I'll try that. Seems a little bit overcomplicated than before

Comment: I'll check on that asap and come back with a confirmation. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, based on the link you have sent it is written:

> **Endpoint URL:**
> Endpoints for all business information, attributes, categories, chains and locations search are accessible at https://mybusinessbusinessinformation.googleapis.com/v1/ instead of https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/
>
> The path name for locations endpoints has changed **from**
> accounts/accountId/locations/locationId **to** locations/locationId

Maybe it was better if you could provide the request uri in the previous version so we could help you more precisely. Anyhow, what I tested in the google playground is as follows:

open  [https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground]
after setting your clientId and Authorisation stuff, in the Request URI write

https://mybusinessbusinessinformation.googleapis.com/v1/locations/XXXXX?readMask=storeCode,metadata,profile,serviceArea,labels,adWordsLocationExtensions
[image]

instead of XXXXX, write your locationId
you can write different readMask fields, The possible fields for readMask are:
play with different fields to check if you have your desired one or not         readMask="storeCode,regularHours,name,languageCode,title,phoneNumbers,categories,storefrontAddress,websiteUri,regularHours,specialHours,serviceArea,labels,adWordsLocationExtensions,latlng,openInfo,metadata,profile,relationshipData,moreHours";

If above does not help you, in the link below I see that all metadata attribute of a location might be:

[image]

Click [here] (https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest/v1/accounts.locations#Location.Metadata)

Comment: I am interested in flag isVerified. This one is not returned in metadata object. It is clearly visible in the screen you provided.

Comment: I asked the same question on Google Support: https://support.google.com/business/thread/145526894/gbp-api-locationstate-object-in-business-information-v1-api?hl=en

Comment: I am not sure, but I think it has been deprecated and it is not provided anymore.

Comment: I have the same problem here. Not sure if the new API system added value.